# How to redirect to DocumentRoot by URL

Tags: linux, debian

How I can get files from a directory according to request url in Apache2? I really forgot how to do that.

It's something like:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName panel.mywebsite.com 
    DocumentRoot /opt/panel/scripts/
</VirtualHost>
```

So, If user access this url (panel.mywebsite.com) the server will show the there exists in opt directory.

But doesn't work!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a test file `test.html` and drop it in `/opt/panel/scripts`.
  Put the word `test` in it.
- Your site config should look somewhat like this. You should have lines for logging which are important for debugging.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName panel.mywebsite.com 
    DocumentRoot /opt/panel/scripts
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/panel.mywebsite.com_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/panel.mywebsite.com_access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

*Notice the missing `/` on the end*

- Visit http://panel.mywebsite.com/test.html and look for the word `test`
- If it doesn't work, check your logs for an explanation

Comment: Hi! I discovered by myself. But anyway, thanks for add more information!